# When does Azure DeploymentId change?

Tags: azure

I had couple of questions around DeploymentId:

1. When does Azure DeploymentId change?
2. Does it change when I update a deployment?
3. Does it retain the Id when I swap Production-Staging deployments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deployment ID will only change when you delete the existing deployment and redeploy a new one.  In-place upgrades, Guest OS upgrades, VIP swaps, etc will not change the deployment ID.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried these actions out on the Azure portal and found that the DeploymentId **changes when you update the deployment** but *not when you swap* - if DeploymentId 1 is in Production and 2 is in Staging, performing VIP swap will put 2 in Staging and 1 in Production.

Couldn't find any documentation to back this up, but would love to see some if anybody else finds it.

Comment: An upgrade to a deployment will not change the deployment ID.  Perhaps you did the upgrade via Visual Studio, which depending on your VS settings will do a delete/redeploy?